# Mysql connector on python(Newbie here)

Tags: python, mysql, connector

After i done with my python code i try making it exe and running it, and [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUby3.png)
this is the code for conneting to mysql:
db=mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',user='root',passwd='root',database='item')
im using MYSQL workbench

do i need to install something on my pc to able to run it?
or if i cant use mysql connector to run it is there other way for me to connect to MYSQL workbench? while on exe program

i except the program to able to run into MYSQLworkbench while on exe

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please do not upload errors/code as images, so it is easier for someone to help you. Read this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To connect to a MySQL database in a Python executable (exe) program, you need to ensure that the necessary dependencies are bundled with your executable. When you create an executable using tools like py2exe, pyinstaller, or cx_Freeze, you must make sure that the MySQL connector library is included.

Here are the steps to ensure your Python executable can connect to a MySQL database:

Install MySQL Connector in Your Python Environment:
Make sure you have the mysql-connector-python library installed in your Python environment where you are writing your code. You can install it using pip:

pip install mysql-connector-python

Include the MySQL Connector in the Executable:
When you create your Python executable using tools like py2exe or pyinstaller, ensure that the MySQL Connector library is included in the bundled files. Most of these tools allow you to specify additional files or modules to include. You should include the MySQL Connector library files in your bundle.

Specify Database Connection Parameters:
In your code, specify the database connection parameters as you have done:

db = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost', user='root', passwd='root', database='item')
Handling Dependencies:
Depending on the executable bundling tool you use, you might need to specify additional options or configurations to ensure that the MySQL Connector can find its dependencies when running the executable.

Testing:
After creating the executable, test it on your system to ensure that it can connect to the MySQL database. Make sure to test it on a system where MySQL is installed or where the necessary MySQL client libraries are available.

Remember that creating Python executables can be platform-dependent, so you might need to follow different steps based on the tool you are using and the operating system you are targeting.

Additionally, ensure that your MySQL server (in your case, MySQL Workbench) is running and configured to accept connections from your Python executable. Check that the database user ('root' in your case) has the necessary privileges to connect and perform operations on the 'item' database.

Please note that creating Python executables can sometimes be a complex process, and it may require some troubleshooting to ensure all dependencies are correctly bundled.

Comment: i tried to, pyinstaller --hidden-import mysql-connector-python main.py --onefile
but it look like not working, thanks for replying

Comment: nvm, i found the right imprort thankyou